# Concrete5-8.2.1 php jQuery multiple form validation conflict

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, concrete5-8.x

I have multiple forms on a page (the number can vary depending on the user how many form blocks they add to the page). There are 2 form validation files: the view.js - this is the user side, and controller.php - that's the server side. The form is in a view.php.

I can add unique block IDs to each form and field from the controller. The ID changes every time a new block is placed. So, nothing can be accessed straight as for example $('#name123').

The problems are:

1. How can jQuery know which of the forms needs to be processed? how can it know which of the submit buttons was pressed if the ID number is unknown prior to that?
2. Even if I find out which form was tried to be submitted, how can a unique block ID generated by the controller be processed by jQuery? That is, if I, say, have 3 forms on a page, how can jQuery know which input element fired a signal (e.g. blur)?

Thank you.

some view.php code:

```
<form id="contact_form<?php echo $bUID; ?>" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" 
    action="<?php echo $formAction?>" 
    method="post" 
    accept-charset="utf-8">

    <h2><?php echo $form_title; ?></h2>
    <h2><?php echo $bUID; ?></h2>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="bUID" data-buid="<?php echo $bUID; ?>">-->

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php 
            echo $form->label('name', $entry_name);
            echo $form->text('name'.$bUID, $name, array ('maxlength'=>"50", 'required'=>"required", 'data-buid'=>$bUID));
            echo '<div id="tip-name'.$bUID.'" class="tip-name tip">' . $entry_name_tip . '</div>';
            echo '<div id="error-name'.$bUID.'" class="error-name tip hidden">' . $error_name . '</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
```

some view.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var bUID;

    $('form').submit(function(event){
        bUID = $(this).data("buid");
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm(bUID);
    });

    $('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
        bUID = $(this).data("buid");
        if (!$('#name'+bUID).val() || $('#name'+bUID).val().length < 2 || $('#name'+bUID).val().length > 60) {
            $('#error-name'+bUID).removeClass("hidden");
            $('#tip-name'+bUID).addClass("hidden");
            $('#name'+bUID).addClass("problem");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#error-name'+bUID).addClass("hidden");
            $('#tip-name'+bUID).removeClass("hidden");
            $('#name'+bUID).removeClass("problem");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just create an event listener on form submit and request the id through `this`? Seems easy enough for me.

Comment: Sorry, difficult for me )) The form ID is unknown, so what to listen to? Any examples? Thank you

Comment: `document.addEventListener("submit", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); console.log(e.target.id); });` - The preventDefault will prevent the form from being submitted so you can do something with the target id from that point on. It's up to you to use JS to submit the target form after that.

Comment: how can I combine it with the $(document).ready(function(e)? Or it goes separately? And what about the links, inputs and textarea blur(), on() etc?

Comment: The event listener goes outside of document ready. Though I think it should work perfectly fine inside just as well. Basicly you're not listening to a specific elements submit event, but a global submit event instead. So any submit will trigger it. After that it's a simple matter of "asking which element triggered it with javascript". The same would work with any other event like `blur()`. With the id available to you now, you can simply request that forms values and submit them.

Comment: On a side note: Document Ready just means: Execute this js code _after_ the document has loaded. Anything outside means _before_ the document is loaded. So unless your JS code needs information from the document that doesn't exist yet because it isn't loaded, it's perfectly fine outside of document ready.

Comment: But I think you should actually just post your code. Because it seems to me you're approaching this the wrong way. All you really need to know is how to handle the form on submit. It doesn't matter which form that is. The same goes for `blur()` etc.

Comment: @icecub thank you very much for the tips. my js file is too big to post here. I'll try to implement what you suggested. One question - if I use that outside of Document Ready, how can I then pass the element id to validate? I'll add snippets of code above.

Comment: Just call the function and pass the id along as a parameter. The function can be inside document root.

Comment: I'm not really good at js. if I just use what you wrote, nothing happens. If I use $(document) - it says "TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function[Learn More]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160373/discussion-between-icecub-and-linuxoid).